# Is spark smart enough to avoid redundant values while performing aggregation?

Tags: apache-spark, dataset, aggregation

I have the following Dataset

```
case class Department(deptId:String,locations:Seq[String])

// using spark 2.0.2
// I have a Dataset `ds` of type Department   

+-------+--------------------+
|deptId |      locations     |
+-------+--------------------+
|     d1|[delhi,kerala]      |            
|     d1|[]                  |
|    dp2|[]                  |
|    dp2|[hyderabad]         |       
+-------+--------------------+
```

I intended to convert it to

```
// Dataset `result` of type Department itself

+-------+--------------------+
|deptId |      locations     |
+-------+--------------------+
|     d1|[delhi,kerala]      |            
|    dp2|[hyderabad]         |   
+-------+--------------------+
```

I do the following

```
val flatten = udf(
  (xs: Seq[Seq[String]]) => xs.flatten)

val result = ds.groupBy("deptId").
                agg(flatten(collect_list("locations")).as("locations")
```

My question is, is Spark smart enough not to shuffle around empty `locations` ie `[]` ?

PS: I am not sure if this is a stupid question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no:

- Yes - `collect_list` performs map-side aggregation, so if there are multiple values per grouping key, data will be merged before shuffle.
- No - because an empty list is not the same as the missing data. If that's not the desired behavior you should filter the data first

  ```
  ds.filter(size($"location") > 0).groupBy("deptId").agg(...)
  ```

  but keep in mind that it will yield different result if there are only empty arrays for `deptId`.